# How to convert VCD to DVD?

Tags: windows-7, conversion, dvd, vcd

How do I convert VCD's to DVD's? I searched Google but most of the guides are really old. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to maintain full quality, it is best to not re-encode the video (the VCD video spec is included in the DVD spec). Audio however is not, if you maintain MP2, it needs to be 48 KHz, but since you need to transcode it anyway, you might as well convert it to AC3 (aka A/52) for maximum compatibility.

The following tools assume a Windows OS. Mac and Linux users will have different tools available to them to perform these steps, but the basic steps are the same.

Step 1: Demux VCD Video from Audio
TPMGEnc tools can be used to demux the video and audio from the AV*.DAT files (which are just the MPG files).

Step 2: Transcode the MP2 audio to AC3
BeSweet will transcode the MP2 files to AC3 (use the FFMpeg AC3enc plugin).

Step 3: Mux Video and AC3 Audio into VOB format, preferably with IFO structures. Optionally add chapters here to.
From this point, a simple DVD author program is what's needed. Many with the neat visual interfaces will automatically try to up-covert the resolution in a MPEG-2 transcode... avoid these, they can only degrade the video quality. Something like Muxman (supports chapters!) or VobEdit should work.

Step 4: Make Disc Image (ISO format)
When making the iso for burning, make sure the software supports DVD video compliance and it's checked on. Simply burning the VIDEO_TS structure will not make the DVD playable in hardware players. Burnatonce has a DVD mastering mode which supports this feature.

Step 5: Burn ISO
Well, actually, you may want to test it before wasting a disc to see if the structure will do what you want. Aside from that, any burning program that supports DVD +/- R and image (iso) burning should work. Nero, Roxio, NTI, and many other titles fit this description.

Is this alot of work for the best quality? Yes. There are no automatic scripts for this process, though there out to be. Note that this does not work for SVCD due to the format differences. There are programs that'll do the conversion from s/VCD to DVD automatically for you, but they also up the resolution thus reducing video quality. A simple google search should reveal suitable programs for you.

Most of the programs mentioned can be found at http://www.doom9.org/

Answer (score 2):

There's no straight way that I know of, but you will have to

1. Rip the VCD. http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/186262-VCD-Rip
2. Burn the DVD. http://www.dvdflick.net/
3. Enjoy very low quality DVD

Answer (score 2):

[VCDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_CD) use video/audio streams in [MPEG-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-1) format.  DVDs use streams in a restricted form of [MPEG-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-2) format.  You need (at minimum) an MPEG-2 encoder or (better yet) a DVD authoring tool.

I've used TMPGenc DVD Author in the past for this type of task.  The latest version of their software is [TMPGenc Authoring Works 4](http://tmpgenc.pegasys-inc.com/en/product/taw4.html).  It's not free software, and I haven't used the latest versions, but they offer a trial version.

Another often-recommended program is [ConvertXtoDVD](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/convert%5Fx%5Fto%5Fdvd/).

Answer (score 0):

[convertxtodvd](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/convert_x_to_dvd/) works great for me.